# Debug coffeescript source in Cloud-9 ide?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, cloud9-ide, gulp-sourcemaps

Using Cloud9, set up gulp to compile coffeescript files to javascript with source map. Want to debug it. Now the debugger steps into generated javascript, but not coffeescript files. How to make debugging facilities work with coffeescript code in C9?

Thnks,

Comment: Coud9 only debugs Node and PHP and perhaps Python. Front-end debugging is done via Chrome/Firefox dev tools so you really need to compile to JS first. Cloud9 will not debug coffeescript.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to use node-instector with c9?